# C# : how do you obtain a class' base class?

Tags: c#, superclass

In C#, how does one obtain a reference to the base class of a given class?

For example, suppose you have a certain class, `MyClass`, and you want to obtain a reference to `MyClass`' superclass.

I have in mind something like this:

```
Type  superClass = MyClass.GetBase() ;
// then, do something with superClass
```

However, it appears there is no suitable `GetBase` method.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use Reflection from the Type of the current class.

```
 Type superClass = myClass.GetType().BaseType;
```

Answer (score 23):

```
Type superClass = typeof(MyClass).BaseType;
```

Additionally, if you don't know the type of your current object, you can get the type using GetType and then get the BaseType of that type:

```
Type baseClass = myObject.GetType().BaseType;
```

[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This will get the base type (if it exists) and create an instance of it:

```
Type baseType = typeof(MyClass).BaseType;
object o = null;
if(baseType != null) {
    o = Activator.CreateInstance(baseType);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the type at compile time use the following:

```
object myObject;
Type baseType = myObject.GetType().BaseType;
object o = null;
if(baseType != null) {
    o = Activator.CreateInstance(baseType);
}
```

See [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) and [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to check if a class is subclass of another you can use **is**.

```
if (variable is superclass){ //do stuff }
```

Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Comment: Wauw. This is syntactically sugar. if(this is ClassA)

Answer (score 2):

The [Type.BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) property is what you're looking for.

```
Type  superClass = typeof(MyClass).BaseType;
```

Answer (score 2):

**obj.base** will get you a reference to the parent object from an instance of the derived object *obj*.

**typeof(obj).BaseType** will get you a reference to the parent object's type from an instance of the derived object *obj*.

Comment: `base` and `this` are only available in instance methods.

Answer (score -3):

you can just use ***base.***