# Get BaseType from object in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to find out if the `object` I have is of type `Page`. If I ask for `GetType()` I get `ContentPage`, which is a subclass of `TemplatedPage`, which is a subclass of `Page` (which again is a subclass of `VisualElement` and so on).

My current approach

```
if(parentElement.GetType() == typeof(Page))
{ 
    // do something
}
```

does not work of this. Now I tried to get the `BaseType` as shown in [C# : how do you obtain a class' base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105251/c-sharp-how-do-you-obtain-a-class-base-class). If I do this

```
Type superClass = parentElement.GetType().BaseType;
```

I get

> Error  CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'BaseType' and no extension method 'BaseType' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have `System` namespace included as well as `System.Reflection` and I still get this error. Is it possible to get the `BaseType` in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (parentElement is Page)`? Why are you using reflection for this at all?

Comment: Sometimes it is easier than I thought. Will you provide an answer or should I delete my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to check that out with the [is keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/scekt9xw.aspx). That will take care of the hard work for you.

So like: `if (parentElement is Page) { DoStuffHere(); }`