# How to get all inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, .net-core

Let's imagine that we have a class called `A`, and this class is inherited from class `B`, and also class `B` inherited from class `C`. We can extend this sequence as long as we want. How can we get all classes from this sequence? Like:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# : how do you obtain a class' base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105251/c-sharp-how-do-you-obtain-a-class-base-class)

Comment: Nope. I saw this link before asking this question. But the link that you referenced is about just getting class B. But I want to get all classes that A is inherited from

Comment: Then just repeat this process until you end up on typeof(object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        Type type = typeof(C);
        while (type.BaseType!=null) 
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        }
        // C
        // B
        // A
        // Object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            Console.WriteLine(type);
    }

// These can be in various projects / assemblies
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
class D : B { }
class E { }
class F : E { }
class G : D { }
```

Prints:

```
A
B
C
D
G
```

Comment: With lots of types, this is going to be very slow.

Comment: And it also doesn't catch types outside the executing assembly. So if the object is inherited from another project, it will be missed.

Comment: Agreed. I reckon it will set the OP on the right track though ;-)

Comment: @DavidG yeap, OK, fixed for all loaded assemblies.